# Viewport Settings For Responsive Design

Tags: responsive-design, viewport

Okay,

So I am designing a site which needs to be responsive.

The design is nailed down and I have just been doing some testing.

In order to get my media queries for mobile devices to work, think phones not ipad in this instance, I have set up a media query and everything looks perfect.

In order to make use of these media queries, I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

However, this also has an impact on the ipad version, specifically the portrait version of my site which I do not need to touch.

I guess my question is how can I control which devices pick up the viewport settings?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this on a 'less then this amount of pixels' basis but I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks for all contributions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to use comma separators on meta elements as they are considered key-value pairs:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `maximum-scale` = the maximum level the user is able to zoom in on a webpage, where a value of 1.0 means the user isn't able to at all. You can even make it to where the user cannot zoom - `user-scalable= no`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

should work on every devices resolution. 
The zoom being deactivate though.

Use css media queries to adjust display for every width and height.